# ruby, date string between date string range

Tags: ruby

I have two date strings :

```
lower_limit = '1981-03-27'
upper_limit = '1981-04-27'
```

and a date string:

```
birth_date = '1981-03-29'
```

How to test if birth_date is between lower_limit and upper_limit

Thanks,

Comment: Dates in this format can be compared as strings, using the usual comparison operators (`<`, `<=` etc).

Answer (score 3):

This way

```
(Date.parse(lower_limit)..Date.parse(upper_limit)).cover?(Date.parse(birth_date))
```

Comment: I just found the same, thanks puts (DateTime.parse(lower_limit) .. DateTime.parse(upper_limit)).include?(DateTime.parse(birt_date))

Comment: @Fatna `cover?` actually has a far simpler (and I would assume more efficient) implementation than `include?`. `cover?` just checks that the first value is less than or equal to the test value and the last value is greater than or equal to the test value (for an inclusive range). `include?` does a lot more work than I care to explain in a comment but you can see it here if you like [`Range#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) and 2.5 implementation is cleaner than <= 2.2.